# calling static variable instead of get function

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

I have been working with some code, and see that people use a get function to get a static variable instead of just making it public.

Is there any performance change in this? What is the reasoning behind this.

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction

Ex:

```
public static A obj=new A();
// elsewhere call
a.function();
```

vs

```
private static A obj=new A();
public static void getA(){
return A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no performance benefit if you change to the later version.

The main difference is the access modifier. In your first example, the instance of class A is public which means any other class can access it.
As per the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principal, you should not allow other classes to modify it , hence we should make it private.

This is already followed in your 2nd example. The method getA should return the instance in a Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue, above all, that I see in this solution is that the following may happen:

```
 public class MySingleton {
     public static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
     private MySingleton() { } //private constructor to avoid anyone else from creating an object
     //everthing is fine up to here
     public void doSomething() {}

 }

 public static void aMethod() {
     MySingleton.instance.doSomething();
     //still everything is fine... maybe
 }

 public static void aMethodCalledBeforeThePreviousOne() {
     MySingleton.instance = null;
     // ops :(
 }
```